# ADB command line start activity permissions

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I'm trying to trigger an activity using an intent using adb on the command line:

```
adb shell am start 
 -a android.intent.action.VIEW 
 -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT 
 -t vnd.google.android.package/vnd.google.android.package_something 
 -n com.google.android.package/com.google.android.apps.package.SomeActivity
```

but it throws a security exception:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] typ=vnd.google.android.package/vnd.google.android.package_something cmp=com.google.android.package/com.google.android.apps.package.SomeActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] typ=vnd.google.android.package/vnd.google.android.package_something flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.package/com.google.android.apps.package.SomeActivity } from null (pid=31536, uid=2000) requires com.google.android.package.START_ACTIVITY
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2767)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:885)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:361)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:101)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:251)
```

So I tried again with a user who has the missing permission:

```
adb shell am start 
  -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT 
  -t vnd.google.android.package/vnd.google.android.package_something 
  -n com.google.android.package/com.google.android.apps.package.SomeActivity 
  --user 10088
```

but then it says that the activity doesn't exist:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=    [android.intent.category.DEFAULT] typ=vnd.google.android.package/vnd.google.android.package_something cmp=com.google.android.package/com.google.android.apps.package.SomeActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.google.android.package/com.google.android.apps.package.SomeActivity} does not exist.
```

Am I using the user parameter incorrectly? Do I need to include any more information?

Answer (score 0):

You should start activities using the syntax below:

```
adb shell am start  
-n com.google.android.package/.SomeActivity
```

In your case with user permission:

```
adb shell am start  
-n com.google.android.package/.SomeActivity
--user 10088
```